# In-App Purchasing Password Prompt

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement the restore process for my IAP but it seems to be acting weird. This is how I set it up:

- A button is pressed and `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];` gets called followed by `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];`
- This IMMEDIATELY processes the restoration process although the password prompt comes up. It does NOT wait for the user to input a password before restoring.

This can't be right. It processes the correct restoration product but it does it immediately without the user entering a password. What's the purpose of showing the login prompt if it doesn't use it for restoring purchases?

Comment: I think you need to call `addTransaction` before user taps on anything to bind the controller and finish whatever pending is still going. On the button tap - just call `restoreCompletedTransactions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you are seeing is a transaction from an earlier purchase or restoreCompletedTransactions (for which you entered the password).  Old transactions will keep popping up in updatedTransactions each time you addTransactionObserver until you finally execute a finishTransaction:transaction for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self]` once upon initialization. You can have multiple observers, but Apple recommends against it. After that is called, anything that was in the payment queue is processed.

For the restore part, simply create a `UIButton` that calls a method to do the restoring in your in-app purchasing class.

```
//Button's action
-(void)restoreButtonTapped(UIButton *)button {
     [yourInAppPurchasingClass restoreTransactions];
}
// located in your class that handles IAP
-(void)restoreTransactions {
     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

The delegate for a successful restore is the same as a purchase, but not if it fails. So make sure to implement `- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error`

Comment: When I add the observer a password prompt is shown. Is there a way to clear out orphaned StoreKit purchases? I removed my test user from iTunes Connect but I am still getting the prompt to login to that email even when not logged into ANY iTunes account...

Comment: Always make sure that finishTransaction gets called or you will just keep purchases in limbo. The sandbox and test users get weird at times. Since you deleted the test account, try deleting the app and then logging out that account on your device from Settings -> App Store. Then log in your new test user and give it a go.